# How can i send image with text in servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans

Hi need some help in servlet.

I want to get the image and text from jsp page in servlet, But i am not get the text value.

This is my code Sample.

In JSP

```
<form method="post" action="FileUploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="text" name="name">
        Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="image">
         <br/><br/> 
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"   />
    </form>
```

In Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


     String name =  request.getParameter("name");
     System.out.println("Received From jsp:"+name);

    if(name!=null)
    {       
            ..................

            ..................
     }
```

Here i am getting only null value, but i am sending normally without multipart i got the value, whatever sent by the jsp page.

How can i send image with text value in servlet , This is possible.

Please Help Me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/ which will parse the multipart message.